# How to change the Speed of a force-directed graph in d3.js?

Tags: d3.js, force-layout

I generated a force-directed graph in d3.js v4.

But I want to change the speed of the simulation, which is too fast. So, I want to slow it down. My simulation is below:

```
  var simulation = d3.forceSimulation()
      .force("link", d3.forceLink().id(function (d) { return d.id; }).distance(100).strength(1))
      .force("collide", d3.forceCollide(function (d) { return d.r + 8 }).iterations(16))
      .force("charge", d3.forceManyBody().strength(-700).distanceMin(100).distanceMax(1000))
      .force("center", d3.forceCenter(width / 2, height / 2));
```

I want to make my force directed graph slow.

Comment: Refer the link http://emptypipes.org/2015/02/18/slow_force_directed_graph/

Comment: Stack snippets are for **running** code, and you have none here. I just removed them.

Answer (score 0):

If your issue is that the nodes move around to fast, and you're looking for the plot to converge in a slower manner, use `simulation.alphaDecay`.

From the [simulation.alphaDecay documentation](https://github.com/d3/d3-force#simulation_alphaDecay):

> The alpha decay rate determines how quickly the current alpha interpolates towards the desired target alpha; since the default target alpha is zero, by default this controls how quickly the simulation cools. Higher decay rates cause the simulation to stabilize more quickly, but risk getting stuck in a local minimum; lower values cause the simulation to take longer to run, but typically converge on a better layout. To have the simulation run forever at the current alpha, set the decay rate to zero; alternatively, set a target alpha greater than the minimum alpha.